# Panel footer, background for the entire section

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap panel where the height is automatically generated from a jquery script.

So, I would like to have the footer with a background for the entire section.

[image]

How can I achieve this goal ?
I don't want to fix the height for this section, is it possible to make something like :"height for the rest of your space in the panel".

Here the fiddle:
http://www.bootply.com/XBCffrO0My

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you need to show us the demo of your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table layout approach**

Idea is to have the element behave like a table and the child item as its row which would occupy the entire space.

[**Updated Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/MoZOx5rrNE)

```css
#crud1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-footer {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-footer .row {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="crud1" class="panel panel-primary" style="height: 248px;">

    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
        ChartLine 1
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="label label-success">priusa2</span>

      </div>

      <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 7px;">

        <span class="label label-success status"></span>
      </div>

      <p></p>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-heading closed -->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container-fluidrm">
        No-picture
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-body closed -->
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-md-9">

          <p>Description:</p>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <a class="show-popup" href="#" id="poplink" data-showpopup="ChartLine 1"><span id="logos" class="material-icons"></span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:7px;">
          <span id="logos" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-footer closed -->


  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Flexible box approach**

Give the child item `flex: 1` to expand with the parent element.

[**Updated Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/48x97WS1y6)

```css
#crud1 {
  display: flex; /* Activate flexbox module layout */
  flex-direction: column; /* Align items horizontally */
}
.panel-footer {
  flex: 1; /* Expand with the parent */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="crud1" class="panel panel-primary" style="height: 248px;">

    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
        ChartLine 1
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="label label-success">priusa2</span>

      </div>

      <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 7px;">

        <span class="label label-success status"></span>
      </div>

      <p></p>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-heading closed -->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container-fluidrm">
        No-picture
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-body closed -->
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-md-9">

          <p>Description:</p>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <a class="show-popup" href="#" id="poplink" data-showpopup="ChartLine 1"><span id="logos" class="material-icons"></span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:7px;">
          <span id="logos" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-footer closed -->


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I have to add the unit for some versions of IExplorer.. In any case it is not a best practice to guarantee the compatibility with every browser. Does it ?

Comment: You can use this: http://pleeease.io/play/ The code will support from IE10 and all major browsers.

Comment: I must guarantee the compatibility for IE8

Comment: Added a solution for older browsers.